# React-Native) eas update is success but dose not updated production app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm going to modify and update the app that is distributed on the App Store and Google Play.
I set up `eas` and used `eas update` for this, and I could check the update list in expo.dev.

However, it was not updated in the actual app.  I upgraded the version of expo sdk from 33 to 45. Could this be a problem?
Or are there any other causes you suspect?

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx", "svg"]
    },
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.6.0",
    "sdkVersion": "45.0.0", // before sdk 33
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/app_icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/push_icon.png",
      "color": "#76604b"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "enabled": true,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/....."
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/*",
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxxx",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "프로필 사진 또는 문의 사진 등록을 위해 권한이 필요합니다.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "프로필 사진 또는 문의 사진 등록을 위해 권한이 필요합니다.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "날씨 정보를 읽어 오기 위해 권한이 필요합니다"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.xxx",
      "versionCode": 7,
      "icon": "./assets/images/app_icon.png",
      "splash": {
        "resizeMode": "cover",
        "mdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash.png",
        "hdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash@2x.png",
        "xhdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash@3x.png"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxx"
      }
    },
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    }
  }
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.5.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "channel": "preview"
    },
    "production": {
      "channel": "production"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I'm wasting a lot of time on this issue. Can I get some help with this?

Edit: I use an expo account different from the person who distributed the app before. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and found a solution here. 
[Expo Forums (eas update not working as expected)](https://forums.expo.dev/t/eas-update-not-working-as-expected/69566)

The solution:

```
    import * as Updates from 'expo-updates';
    
    class LoginScreen extends React.PureComponent {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        await this.onFetchUpdateAsync();
      }
    
      onFetchUpdateAsync = async () => {
        try {
          const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
    
          if (update.isAvailable) {
            await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
            await Updates.reloadAsync();
          }
        } catch (error) {
          alert(`Error fetching latest Expo update: ${error}`);
        }
      };
    
       render() {
           return (...)
       }
    }
```

Comment: May be provide the command to update?

Comment: When you want to update the app with the latest code changes using `expo-updates`. You can use the following command:

npx eas-cli update --platform `your platform (ios or android)` --profile `your profile from eas.json`